# Error says I have NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, text, embedding

I am trying to use word embedding then run it through a logistic regression model. I am getting an error saying I have NaN values but I have no NaN values.

```
`X=df["description"] 
y=df["hc_related"]

embeddings_index = dict()
f = open('glove.6B.50d.txt',encoding='UTF8')                      
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

from tqdm import tqdm

embeddings = []
for tweet in tqdm(X):
    base_embedding = np.zeros((50,))
    word_count = 0
    for token in word_tokenize(tweet):
        token = token.lower()
        if token in stopwords.words('english'):
            continue
        try:
            base_embedding += embeddings_index[token]
            word_count +=1
        except:
            continue
    base_embedding = base_embedding/word_count
    embeddings.append(base_embedding)      
    
    
X = np.array(embeddings)
    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.3, 
                                                    random_state=0,
                                                    stratify = y)
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=300)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_hat = model.predict(X_test)
round(accuracy_score(y_test,y_test_hat) * 100,2)
```

`

I have run I've run np.isnan(X) np.isnan(y) and df['hc_related'].isnull().values.any() on the data and got a False output which indicates that there are no NaN values. I believe it was something to do with my X and y when trying to run the model but I'm not sure the issue

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use Double Precision Float If You Are using float64

The Mistake You Have Made here is this

```
line in f:
values = line.split()
word = values[0]
coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
embeddings_index[word] = coefs
```

Comment: I tried that already and the error remains the same